# custom-file-input label not shown in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to display a label above a custom file input field and another label inside it with bootstrap 4. I tried the following, but the `label 1` is not shown.

```
<label class="w-100">label 1
  <input type="file" class="custom-file-input">
  <label class="custom-file-label">label 2</label>
</label>
```

When I label a normal input field this way, `label 3` is shown as expected.

```
<label class="w-100">label 3
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
</label>
```

Does anybody know why `label 1` is not shown and what I should do to display `label 1` and `label 2`? Many thanks in advance.

What actually does work is this:

```
<label for="some-id" class="w-100">label 1</label>
<div class="custom-file" style="margin-top:-1.5em" id="some-id">
  <input type="file" class="custom-file-input">
  <label class="custom-file-label">label 2</label>
</div>
```

but the negative margin seems to be a bad solution. Without it, the label is displayed to high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just write a basic **bootstrap 4 custom file label** code, I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<label class="w-100">label 1
  <div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input">
    <label class="custom-file-label">label 2</label>
  </div>
</label>
```

Comment: Sorry, I see the both labels now, but I get a warning <form> is not allowed here, and it breaks other html code when I put `label 1` around it. .. are you sure this is correct?

Comment: When I use <label for= ...> I do not get the error, but the label is placed differently above the input, as in my example with `label 3`, which kind of destroys the layout of my form .. any ideas?

Comment: I just update the code as per your requirement. Just add `custom-file` class in `label` will resolve your issue. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for all your help. But when I paste your code into my template, I cannot see label 1..

Comment: Can you share the link for more clarification? Thanks

Comment: Of course, I was refering to the starter template here. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: I just update the above code snippet, I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, this works indeed! (Sorry for the late feedback)

Comment: I think what prevented me from trying what you suggested in the first place is that  I get a warning 'Element div is not allowed here' (in pycharm). Since it seems to work anyway, I am happy. If you have any idea why this is the case, I'd still be glad if you could tell me..

Comment: Sure we'll discuss tomorrow in a chat and I'm not clear what are you asking. but we'll discuss on a chat.

Answer (score 2):

Just run this:

```js
$(".custom-file-input").on("change", function() {
  var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
  $(this).siblings(".custom-file-label").addClass("selected").html(fileName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
  <div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hello there, I think this javascript solution is a little overkill for the problem, but thanks anyway for your answer.

Comment: You don't really need the jQuery

Comment: Notice this does not handle inputs with the `multiple` attribute where you can select multiple files.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to support multiple file selection (using the `multiple` attribute) here is the code for that.

```
$('.custom-file-input').on('change', function () {
    let fileName = Array.from(this.files).map(x => x.name).join(', ')
    $(this).siblings('.custom-file-label').addClass("selected").html(fileName);
});
```

Comment: Great solution :)